# IE rendering before-ajax-state when hitting page via forward/back button

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

The problem is this:
When I change the content on a page via AJAX and then use the browsers back and forward button to go to the same page, then I will be presented with the content of the page before the AJAX was executed.

This seems to be specific to IE (confirmed on version 8), as Firefox will render the last version of the page.

Just to clarify, I don't need (nor want for usability reasons) to replay the AJAX calls when clicking back/forward.

We were thinking about firing the last AJAX call on page load (if that event is even triggered), but we would like not to force everyone to wait through the additional AJAX call when going to the page the second time, also this would cause the first real load of the page to be slower as well.

Maybe someone has a good solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956563/remember-ajax-added-data-when-hitting-back-button

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be useful : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-rad2/ ;)

Comment: If I understand it correctly this would add an additional back button to the page outside the default browser navigation buttons. Unfortunatly we tried this in on of our other apps and we found that our typical user will nearly always click the browsers buttons and we don't think it's a very user friendly feature. It certainly doesn't work with our visitors who will only be on the site for a few minutes (ideally).