# AJAX Search Back Button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to sort out the use of the back button with an AJAX search I built and I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm using `localStorage` as instructed by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956563/remember-ajax-added-data-when-hitting-back-button) with this code:

```
// Replace the search result table on load.
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    if ('myTable' in localStorage && window.location.hash) {
        $("#myTable").html(localStorage.getItem('myTable'));
    }
}

// Save the search result table when leaving the page.
$(window).unload(function () {
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        var form = $("#myTable").html();
        localStorage.setItem('myTable', form);
    }
});
```

I'm having trouble sorting out how to properly clear the `localStorage`. With the above code the users can perform a search, click a link, click back, and their results will be re-populated. However, if they leave the site and come back later or refresh the search-page their results persist. How can I work around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
localStorage.clear(); // <-- clears all local storage for domain
```

or for single items

```
localStorage.removeItem('myTable');
```

If you don't like how localStorage persists until removed manually by client, there is also sessionStorage  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

> sessionStorage
>
> This is a global object (sessionStorage) that maintains a storage area that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.
>
> // Save data to a the current session's store

```
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");
```

> // Access some stored data

```
alert( "username = " + sessionStorage.getItem("username"));
```

> The sessionStorage object is most useful for hanging on to temporary data that should be saved and restored if the browser is accidentally refreshed.